# Will setting this.constuctor = this cause a circular reference/memory leak

Tags: javascript, oop, memory-leaks, constructor, circular-reference

The following code works, but am I running the risk of causing circular reference or a memory leak?

```
/* core package */
var core = function() {
    // Throw an error, the core package cannot be instantiated.
    throw new Error('A package cannot be instantiated.');
};

core.Container = function (properties){
    this.constructor = this;
    this.id = null;
    if ('id' in properties)
        this.id = properties['id'];
    else 
        throw new Error('A container must have an id.');
}
core.Container.prototype = new Object();

var container = new core.Container({'id': 'container'});
alert(container instanceof core.Container); // Result is true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by @Raynos in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)

> @Utilitron depends what you mean by leaks are we talking leaks in
> decent engines or leaks in IE6 That code shouldnt leak in v8

Answer (score 0):

when you assign

```
core.Container.prototype = new Object();
```

new core.Container **instances** are assigned Object as their constructor-

**this** only refers to the constructor function itself, whose constructor should be Function.

Assign `core.Container.prototype.constructor=core.Container`

Comment: Either way, assigning `prototype.constructor` or `this.constructor = this`, if you `alert(container.constructor)` you get the same result or if you `alert(container instanceof core.Container);` you get the same result. So it doesn't seem to matter how the constuctor gets assigned, the code works.

Comment: If you follow the stack, without setting `core.Container.prototype = new Object();` and just declare the function (without the `this.constructor = this;`) `alert(container instanceof core.Container);` will result as true, and `alert(container.constructor);` will result as a String representation of the `core.Container`. After you set `core.Container.prototype = new Object();` it reassigns `core.Container.constructor` and `alert(container.constructor);` will return the string representation of the Object code. setting `core.Container.prototype.constructor=core.Container` assigns it back

Comment: by declaring `this.constructor = this`, it seems to be bypassing several reassignment steps.